# Cutting and pasting from vim and tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

Is cutting and pasting from a vim session started from tmux completely broke?

If I want to cut from a github web into my vim session or vice versa, it rarely works or if it does, it is completely broke.

I have had others confirm that they find this difficult.

I am running on the following:

- OS X 10.8.2
- Vim 7.3
- tmux 1.7

I am referring to the normal cut and paste commands <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

Are there any fixes or workarounds?

Comment: Pasting from any app into Vim within tmux (and vice versa) works well if you configure your environment correctly. What OS? What Vim version? What tmux version? How do you paste in Vim? How do you yank? How do you expect people to solve your problem if you are not just a little bit more precise than that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. In Vim, you don't use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to "copy" and "paste": you use `y`/`p`, possibly with a register (`"*y`/`"ap`) to "yank" and "put".
2. If your Vim has clipboard support built-in, `"*y` should be enough to yank from Vim and `"*p` should be enough to put from another application. `*` is the "clipboard" register.
3. Again, supposing Vim has clipboard support, adding `set clipboard^=unnamed` to your `~/.vimrc` should synchronize Vim's default register and the clipboard register; allowing you to simply use `y`˘and `p`.
4. The tmux/vim combo has a long standing issue with system clipboard on Mac OS X. It is fortunately [very quick and easy to fix](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard).

To see if your Vim build has clipboard support, type this command in your shell:

```
$ vim --version | grep clipboard
```

A `+` before a feature means "supports", `-` means "doesn't support".

Comment: Finally I can cut and paste.  What a relief!

Comment: This is the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 0):

just to add a little bit help.

[getting vim with clipboard support](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/11/getting-vim-with-clipboard-support/) might be helpful